# Get all unique values from a collection array object field

Tags: mongodb

I have the collection `sessions`:

```json
[
    {
      "_id": "",
      "members": [
        { "user_id": "11", "joined_at": "2023-06-15T04:50:06.298Z" },
        { "user_id": "23", "joined_at": "2023-06-15T04:50:06.298Z" },
        { "user_id": "73", "joined_at": "2023-06-15T04:50:06.298Z" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "",
      "members": [
        { "user_id": "59", "joined_at": "2023-06-15T04:50:06.298Z" },
        { "user_id": "37", "joined_at": "2023-06-15T04:50:06.298Z" },
        { "user_id": "11", "joined_at": "2023-06-15T04:50:06.298Z" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "",
      "members": [
        { "user_id": "11", "joined_at": "2023-06-15T04:50:06.298Z" },
        { "user_id": "23", "joined_at": "2023-06-15T04:50:06.298Z" },
        { "user_id": "28", "joined_at": "2023-06-15T04:50:06.298Z" }
      ]
    }
]
```

I want to get all distinct `user_id` values from the entire collection (or based on a filter). Based on the documents above, the intended results should be:

```js
["11", "23", "73", "59", "37", "28"]
```

I know that the collection.distinct() function exists, but I'd like to see how it's done for objects fields in an array.

Answer (score 0):

1. `$group` - Group all documents and add the `members.user_id` array into the `user_ids` array. This results in the `user_ids` being a nested array.
2. `$set` - Set `user_ids` field.

   2.1. `$setUnion` - Union the elements from the result *2.1.1*. This results in the elements are distinct.

   2.1.1. `$reduce` - Flatten the nested array `user_ids`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      user_ids: {
        $addToSet: "$members.user_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      user_ids: {
        $setUnion: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$user_ids",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value",
                "$$this"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zb_CW2bq4eU)

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
  Expected Output:
  [
    {
      members: ['11', '23', '73', '59', '37', '28'],
    },
  ]

  step 1: unwind members
  step 2: group by null and add to set members.user_id
  step 3: project members
  
*/

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: '$members',
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      members: {
        $addToSet: '$members.user_id',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      members: 1,
    },
  },
]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).